# Connect product extension to custom entity and add to administration

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I’ve created a custom entity, lets call it my_entity, and added a StringField called name. After that I created an admin section with a list view and detail page. The list view shows all the entries from my_entity and within the detail page you can create or edit an entry. So far so good.

Then I created a product extension. But this is the part where I’m stuck. The extension will use a separate DB table, my_entity_extension. The extension and the DB table need to reference to a product and my_entity. A product can have multiple references to an entry from my_entity.

How will the productExtension, in particular the extendFields, look like? Do I need to use a OneToOneAssociationField or a ManytoOne?

Then my next question, I couldn’t quit find this in the documentation. I extended the product view tab in the administration. Now I want to add a sw-entity-multi-select component which is linked to my_identity but I need to save the selection in the product extension. How can I get this to work in the Twig and JS file?

Also what I noticed is that if I enable the autoload in the product extension, then the product overview list is empty. No products are showing in the admin. Once I set it to false, it’s showing again.

A lof of questions but hopefully someone can help me out.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Do I need to use a OneToOneAssociationField or a ManytoOne?

This really depends on your intended use. Shall multiple products be associated to one single record of your custom entity? Then it's `ManyToOne`. Shall there be one unique record of your custom entity per plugin? Then it's `OneToOne`. See the documentation with [examples to each kind of association](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-data-associations#example-entity-definitions).

You can then use the `extension` property of the `product` entity to store values for associations to the extended entity.

Assuming you override `sw-product-settings-form` to place the field in the administration:

```js
Component.override('sw-product-settings-form', {
    template,
    inject: ['repositoryFactory'],
    computed: {
        someProperty: {
            get() {
                return this.product.extensions.yourEntity?.someProperty ?? null;
            },
            set(value) {
                if (!this.customer.extensions.yourEntity) {
                    this.$set(this.product.extensions, 'yourEntity', this.repositoryFactory.create('your_entity').create());
                }

                this.$set(this.product.extensions.yourEntity, 'someProperty', value);
            },
        },
    }
});
```

In your override's template:

```html
<sw-text-field
    v-model="someProperty"
/>
```

Changes to the field will then be persisted when saving the product. [Here's an example plugin](https://github.com/dneustadt/DneCustomerHeightExtension) that extends the customer module with an extension field in the same manner.

Comment: I'm overriding sw-product-detail to include a new tab. Then I'm adding the tab in view/sw-product-detail-newtab/sw-product-detail-newtab.html.twig and it's registered as a new component in the JS file. Can I then still use "this.product.extensions" and in your example you're using a sw-text-field, but I want to load the entity items through a sw-entity-multi-select. I can't figure out how I can load the items.

Comment: @JackyRaimond how did you do it? I am having the same problem